# Limit iOS's app access to sound output

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, audio

I am a new iPhone user, because Apple has formed an amazing partnership with Cochlear Corp (hearing-implant devices), so I can directly pair my cochlear implant with my iPhone. The app for this is called [Nucleus Smart](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nucleus-smart/id1210236531?mt=8), but it has pretty limited functionality.

One issue is that when I open any app that can access sound, it switches automatically to my hearing aid. For example, even my solitaire app, with the sound option turned off, will still automatically turn on my hearing aid, and essentially mask all regular environmental sounds with the muted audio.

The developers of the app aren't particularly responsive, so I'm wondering if there is another app that can block app access to any sound output.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in the Settings and I am sure this is no app to do this without a jailbreak. Some apps offer an option to turn off sounds in Settings, but if there aren’t any options there is no way to go around it.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant in the post is that even when I turn the sound off in the app, it still activates my hearing aid when I open the app.

Comment: @adam_g probably a hearing aid problem

Comment: As I mentioned, the developers are not very responsive so I'm looking for a broader solution.

Comment: A (small) start would be to let Apple know what you are experiencing at the [iPhone Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) page.